# Not able to import any sql file using command line in windows xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database, command-line, import

I am trying to import some .sql file (which contains my database) into xampp mysql database but no luck.

Here is my attempts :

step-1: I Entered into c:\xampp\mysql\bin>

step-2: And then used this command for import my sql file to my local database (I placed 'raj-db.sql' in 'c:\xampp\mysql\bin>' folder).

Step-3: After click on enter it is asking 'Enter password:' and immediately going to 'c:\xampp\mysql\bin>' path with out enter any password.

Please can you help me on this.I installed fresh xampp also but still behaving the same.

It is coming like this

**c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p my-db-name < file-name.sql

Enter password:

c:\xampp\mysql\bin>**

If I run 'c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql' it is coming as 'MariaDB [none]>'.But usually it should come like 'mysql>'.

Comment: Verify that your msyql is running .

Comment: yes, it is running..php application with database is working fine..but I am getting this problem.

Comment: boos Note that you password will not be visible when entered.

Comment: "raj181"  is not my password, it's my database name which i created for import sql file.my password is default [empty].

Answer (score 0):

### How to Load MySQL Database Dump Using XAMPP

- Step 1 : Start your Xampp
- Step 2 : Start your MySQL Server *(if not already started)*
- Step 3 : Launch into CLI mode by clicking on the CMD button (black
  button).
- Step 4 : Copy your Database backup into same directory.
- Step 5 : Load the backup into your already created Database using the
  following command

  `mysql -u root -p DatabaseName < DatabaseDump.sql`

*You may use the attached screenshots as your guide.*

Hope this helps.

[image: Start your XAMPP and MySQL Server]

[image: Start MySQL Server in XAMPP]
[image: Loading Mysql Database Dump]

Answer (score 0):

Does the target database is already created? Import needs it created and empty for it to work.

```
CREATE DATABASE db-name
```

If it is already created try this and then import with your command:

```
use db_name;
```